# Table centers content in cell - I want the opposite

Tags: html, cell, center, css-tables

My table is centering its contents right in the vertical-middle of it. I didn't apply any stylesheets to it, but: `border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"`.

At this moment it's like this:

[image]

Though I want it like this:

[image]

The X's do not represent simple text! In my case they're other tables inside one single table: The black box is a table. The blue and green boxes are table cells and the red Xes are also tables. One table in the blue - and one table in the green cell.

Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 3):

Table cells are vertically centered by default. Give each cell

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I did only try that on the cell's content yet :P

Comment: Is it just me, or does anybody else struggle with getting vertical-align to work properly? Sadly, I usually settle on valign="top"...

Comment: @Jim it should work, as long as you put it on the cell, not the whole table